# UITextField stops working when setting delegate to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitextfield

I'm not sure why this is happening, wondering if someone can help.

I currently have a UITextfield delegate set to the ViewController. I've declared all the necessary methods. When I start typing, nothing shows up, but it is being detected per the NSLog I've inserted.

When I remove the delegate, then the text fields begins to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the code you are writing in the delegate for the textfield

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

must return YES

    textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

must also return YES

Comment: thanks @user2387149. It was - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange not returning YES. I had an if condition that was copied in there from a script that determines to scroll when a UITextfield is covered by keyboard.

Comment: you are welcome, going to post it as an answer anyway so people can see it right a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

must return YES at some point

`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

must also return YES